# How to fix some faults on Texture Caused by Wrong Edge Slide?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have finished my mesh and textured it. Although, i moved some edges with "Edge Slide" and by checking in "Correct UVs", i see some faults (stretched parts) on it as in the picture below. How can i fix it ?[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuiiM.png)

Comment: UV unwrap your object again when you are done editing the geometry.

Comment: Is there not any way after unwrapping UV map ? Because i arranged it before so i wanted to know before i redo it.

Comment: You can edit the UV map manually in the UV/Image editor, but in my opinion is easier to unwrap.

Comment: For the future: You don't have need to unwrap the *entire* UV map. You can Hide all the parts of your mesh except the parts that need re-unwrapping and then do it.

Comment: @Mentalist, That is a good tip. I can keep it in mind for next time!